# How to package a large Python project using cxFreeze into a single exe (directory not found error)

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, project, cx-freeze

I'm working on a Python project right now using customtkinter and opencv. This project contains multiple directories with python files inside, all in the src directory. There is also a Data directory and Resources directory that store the current data and he resources needed for the app respectively. In order to make this project easier to distribute and use for the end-user, I am trying to use cxFreeze to freeze the whole thing into a single exe that can be simply run by the user. Here is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

And this is what I have in my setup.py file:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

include_files = ['QRCodeAttendanceV2', 'src']

options = {
    'build.exe': {
        'include_files':include_files
    }
}

setup(
    name="QR Attendance",
    version=0.1,
    description="A QR-based attendance system utilizing JSON data storage (local)",
    executables=[Executable("main.py",base="Win32GUI")],
    options=options
)
```

However, when I run the exe file that is generated by `python setup.py build` I get this error:
[image: Error Message: src Directory not found]

This project also has a virtual environment with all the necessary dependencies installed already

Initially, I tried going online for potential solutions to this issue and I saw that the `include_files` option was used fairly often tominclude a directory, so I added that option to my setup.py file as you can see above but I'm still getting the exact same error. I also tried running the build command from the root directory (QRCodeAttendanceV2) but that didn't work since there's no main.py in the root directory. What is the best way to include all those files into the cxFreeze build?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some experimentation, the solution to this issue is simply to take the setup.py file and move it outside of the src directory. Once that is done, the exe files runs properly and the program works correctly.
[image]